# Finding service history of ancestor in Abwehr during World War 2?

Tags: military-records, germany, world-war-2

I have evidence that my ancestor worked under a pseudonym in the [Abwehr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abwehr).

He joined the allied forces in April 45 in Italy.

I have his British war record, but not his German one.

I have asked the German Embassy for the latter, but have had no reply.

Can you provide advice on where to get help with this?

I know both his name and pseudonym.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Something you need to be aware of from our [Help](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is "Please note: You must not include here in any circumstances information (including name, date and place of birth or any other details) that would allow identification of any living (or possibly) living individual by somebody reading this site. In practice, this means details about anyone born in the last 100 years, whether they are believed to be deceased or not, and whether or not they have given their permission."

Comment: For now I will remove your ancestor's name from your question but if you can assure us that he was born before 1915 then we can easily put it back. Alternatively, even without using his name, more generic advice offered in answers may be able to lead you to the same result.

Comment: Could you please provide some basic background on your ancestor (place of birth, year of birth, nationality) and what kind of evidence you have for your claims?

Comment: Abwehr was divided up into a branch in each military district (Wehrkreis) called an 'Abwehrstelle' or 'Ast.' It would be helpful to know which he was active/ recruited in. There you could focus your efforts in the first instance.

Answer (score 2):

The administrative unit managing all the information of members of the German armed forces during WW2 ("Wehrmacht") is the WASt ("Wehrmachtsauskunftsstelle") https://www.dd-wast.de/en/home.html. You can enter a tracing request directly at their website.

I'm not sure whether the Abwehr was part of the Wehrmacht or not but the WAst might at least be able to tell you.

A good guide for offices that may provide information on members of German army, etc. during WW2 can be found here: http://www.lexikon-der-wehrmacht.de/Suche-R.htm but unfortunately it is in German only.